# Calculate average number from char array

Tags: c++

Im trying to calculate the average out of a couple of number inside an char array. The reason for this is that i imported data from a text document and i made it read only every 2nd line to get the numbers that i wanted.

Now i need to get the average out of these numbers but i cant make it work. I'm starting to get mad about this and i feel that the solution would be rather simple.

EDIT:
The file consists of names and numbers. I.e:

Jason Smith

32

Mary Jane

52

Stevie Wonder

68

Micheal Jackson

59

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double averageNum(char array[], int size) { // A function to calculate the average number

    int sum = 0;
    double avg;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

        array[i]+= sum;

    }

    avg = sum / size;
    return avg;
}


int main(){

    char age [50][30];
    double avg;
    int rows = 0;

    ifstream elevInfo("elevinfo.txt"); // Opens a stream to get data from the document

    if (! elevInfo){    // Error message if the file couldn't be found

        cout << "Could not find the file elevinfo.txt" << endl;
        return (1);
    }


    while(elevInfo.getline(age[rows/2], 30)){ // Reading every 2nd line to an array

        rows++;

    }

    avg = averageNum(age[], rows); // Function call with the numbers from the array and the variable rows as a pointer
    cout << "Average age equals: " << avg << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please describe better your input file (a snippet will be great).

Comment: this is an error: `array[i]+= sum;`. it should be `sum += array[i];`. But be shure, that you want to add the numeric value of a char to the sum, e.g. 'A' == 65 !

Comment: Edited with the file.

Thats true, it wasn't correct. But i'm getting a error from the function call in the end of the code. "Expected expression". 
If i remove the brackets i get another error: "No matching function for call to 'averageNum'"

Comment: The root error is not using your debugger effectively/

Comment: Sorry, i'm at a beginner state. How could i use my debugger more effectively?

Comment: @antabuz With a debugger you are able to step your code one instruction at a time (and see all values of variables at that time), and see where it diverges from your expectations.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess that would be good to do. Do you have any more straight-forward advices?

Comment: I also tried this: 
    for(int i=0; i<rows/2; i++){
    sum+= age[i];

But it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

this is one of many possible solutions for your problem:

```
int main()
{
    // Opens a stream to get data from the document
    ifstream elevInfo("elevinfo.txt"); 
    // Error message if the file couldn't be found
    if (!elevInfo)
    {
        cout << "Could not find the file elevinfo.txt" << endl;
        return (1);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int lineCounter = 0;

    // loop till end of file
    while (!elevInfo.eof())
    {
        // prepare buffer
        char line[30];
        // read line into buffer
        elevInfo.getline(line, 30);

        // do this every second line
        if (lineCounter % 2 == 1)
        {
            // get age as int using function atoi()
            int age = atoi(line);
            // increase sum by the current age
            sum += age;
        }
        // increment line-counter
        lineCounter++;
    }

    // calculate the average
    // divide lineCounter by 2 because only every second line in your file contains an age
    double avg = sum / (lineCounter / 2.0);
    cout << "Average age equals: " << avg << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see it also doesn't need the function `averageNum`.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote my own version of it with your help. Basically i've been looking for "if (lineCounter & 2 == 1)" for waaay to long.

Had to change sum from an int to a double, otherwise the avg didnt come out as a whole.

Comment: @antabuz that's fine! You don't have to change sum to a double, just change this line `double avg = sum / (lineCounter / 2);` to `double avg = sum / (lineCounter / 2.0);`. The expression inside the brackets (int divided by double) results as double and the second division also results as double because of the first division. I also edited the answer.